# How to create four equal buckets of decimal values

Tags: excel

I have an excel table:

```
JobA  .03445
JobB  .01366
JobC  .93271
JobD  .6335
```

Plus 65,000 more.

What I need to do, is to create four equal buckets based on the values.  where the sum of all Jobs in each bucket come as close to the other three buckets as possible.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach based on the incremental percentage. So you sum each incremental job until your sum reaches 25% of total values (that is BucketA), jobs from 25-50% will be "BucketB", 50-75% "BucketC", and rest will go into "BucketD". Sum of values in each bucket should be pretty close since you have 65k of values.

enter this formula

```
=IF(SUM($B$2:B2)/SUM($B$2:$B$100000)<0.25,"BucketA",IF(SUM($B$2:B2)/SUM($B$2:$B$100000)<0.5,"BucketB",IF(SUM($B$2:B2)/SUM($B$2:$B$100000)<0.75,"BucketC","BucketD")))
```

in cell `C1` and drag it to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of studies into algorithms that solve these types of problems. Your problem is actually the exact same format as the equal piles example in this article:

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP#Example

Considering the volume you're working with and the fairly narrow range of values, you could get a fairly good approximate solution by simply doing this:

1. Sort all items in descending order by value
2. In an adjacent column, put 1, 2, 3 and 4 against the first 4 values.
3. Use autofill to repeat that pattern against all values
4. You should now have 4 groups of fairly equal value